# How can I update a column value of a table in DB1 with a column value from a table in DB2?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to perform a simple update in SQL between 2 tables from different DB's. The challenge is that in order for the value to be updated it must meet certain conditions. I have used the join statements to meet the conditions and when I go to test the value from table B it is not being updated into table A. Here is what I've done so far.

```
USE [dbo]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE
(
    @User_ID = INT,
    @Batch_ID VARCHAR(32)
)

DECLARE @locid int 

SELECT @locid 
FROM OtherDB.dbo.User AS UL 
WHERE UL.User_ID = @User_Id 
and User_Type = 1;

UPDATE M 
SET 
    M.Number = W.Number
FROM dbo.tableA AS W
JOIN dbo.tableB AS B ON B.ID = W.ID
JOIN dbo.tableC AS C ON C.ToolA = B.ToolA
JOIN dbo.tableD as D ON D.Zone = W.Zone_Name
JOIN OtherDB.dbo.tableMax AS M ON M.LID = @locid
    AND M.Tool = C.Other_Tool
    AND M.Zone = D._Other_Zone
    AND M.Station = W.Station
WHERE W.User_ID = @User_ID
    AND W.Batch_ID = @Batch_ID

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Sorry will do thanks

Answer (score 0):

The update statement is updating table M in otherDB, not table A on the current database.

You might revise the stored procedure to be

```
Update A
Set A.Number = W.Number
From dbo.tableA A
....
```

Comment: Josh Potts thanks, is there a way to rearrange the joins to maintain the condition comparison I have in place?

Comment: Order for inner joins does not logically change anything. Just change the alias in the first line of your UPDATE statement as suggested (though note that Josh changed the alias for TableA to the rather obvious value of "A" from "W". Also remove the alias for the updated column - that is redundant. I think you want to set Number in A with the value from M.Number - an accidental typo in Josh's statement. Cryptic aliases are a bad habit.

Comment: @SMor is right, you can just change the update statement.